# How to change order in ui-router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a cenario where I have a list and want to reorder it. I'm still new on ui-router and I couldnt figure out how to do it.

My states is something like this (with resolve to pass the data):

```
$stateProvider
    .state('shoppings-view', {
        url: '/shoppings/:id',
        templateUrl: 'shoppings/partial/shoppings-view/shoppings-view.html'
    }).state('shoppings-view.order', {
        url: '/:order',
        templateUrl: 'shoppings/partial/shoppings-view/shoppings-view.html'
    });
```

And here my controller:

```
angular.module('shoppings').controller('ShoppingsViewCtrl',function($scope, $stateParams){

    $scope.order = $stateParams.order != undefined ? $stateParams.order : 'id';
}
```

And a simple view with use a ng-repeat to show them.
The problem is: if I'm in the url: /shoppings/1 and change the link to /shoppings/1/date the controller is not recalled and I can't change the order. So, how can I do something like that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This scenario with `ui-router` could have two *(if not even more)* solutions. Check both of them here in [this working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/XtZTHq?p=preview). We can firstly continue with your Paren-Child scenario, we just have to do few changes

```
// Parent - Child Scenario
.config(['$stateProvider',
  function($stateProvider) {

  // parent child
  $stateProvider
    .state('shoppings-view', {
      url: '/shoppings/:id',
      templateUrl: 'tpl.shoppings-view.html',
      controller: 'ParentCtrl',
    })
    .state('shoppings-view.order', {
      url: '/:order',
      template: '<div>some child content if needed</div>',
      controller: 'ChildCtrl',
    });

 }])
.controller('ParentCtrl', function($scope, $state, $stateParams, DataSvc) {
  $scope.data = [];
  // parent declares method on a $scope
  $scope.load = function(params){
    $scope.data = DataSvc.getAll(params)
  }
  $scope.load($stateParams);
})
.controller('ChildCtrl', function($scope, $state, $stateParams) {
  // child scope has inherit that function
  // and calls the parent to relaod with new params
  $scope.load($stateParams);
})
```

What we can see here, is that child gets the $scope inherited (see [Understanding Scopes](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)) and therefore has access to a parent method **`$scope.load($stateParams);`**. Whenever there is new child state with new param invoked, it calls parent to relaod the data.

Maybe not the best here, but the concept of published methods on parent $scope, available for a child(ren) is a feature I do use a lot...

Second approach could be to move all that stuff into one simple state, with more params:

```
// scenario with Single state
.config(['$stateProvider',
    function($stateProvider) {

  // single state
  $stateProvider
    .state('shoppings', {
      url: '/shoppings-single/:id/:order',
      templateUrl: 'tpl.shoppings-single.html',
      controller: 'SingleCtrl',
      resolve : {
        data : function($stateParams, DataSvc){
          return DataSvc.getAll($stateParams)
        }
      }
    }); 

}])
.controller('SingleCtrl', function($scope, $state, $stateParams, data) {
  $scope.data = data;
  $scope.orderBy = $stateParams.order;
})
```

There is nothing special, just we can see that one state can have more params (see [URL Parameters](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#url-parameters))

All that together check [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/XtZTHq?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you. Great anwser, now I can understand better the use of states.

Comment: Is the first part of this answer outdated? the ui-router docs say "Nothing else is inherited (no controllers, templates, url, etc)."  https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-and-Nested-Views#what-do-child-states-inherit-from-parent-states

Answer (score 2):

You have the same template for the parent and child state, which doesn't make much sense. Are you nesting an identical template inside itself?

A child state includes its parent state. So anything in the parent state template is included in the child state.

Comment: I'm little lost about the states yet. I saw the documentation, some examples, and tutorials. I kind of understood the deep state. But I was using ngRoute and I'm trying to use the ui-router (looks better). And got stuck in this simple thing. I want the same view, same controller, that has a list and I can change the order with params. The child state is only because I cant use the same state with 2 diferent url. I want use /something/:id and /something/:id/:order or /something/:id?order=id

Comment: I stand corrected. You can chain the route parameters, as per Radim's answer.