# AngularUI Router: pass url params to 'abstract' state while calling child state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-router

I want to access the url parameter($stateParam) inside a abstract state while calling a child state. I am curious to know how that can be done. Code in [plunker also](http://plnkr.co/edit/L0TXx3DCBOJmh4XydXbV?p=preview)

```
$stateProvider
    .state('contacts', {
        abstract: true,

        //my whole point is to get the id=1 here :(

        url: '/contacts/:id',
        templateUrl: function($stateParams){
            console.log("Did i get the child's parameter here? " + $stateParams.id)
            return 'contacts' + $stateParams.id + '.html'; //this will have a ui-view in it which will render its detail.
        }
    })

    .state('contacts.detail', {
        url: '/:id',
        // loaded into ui-view of parent's template
        templateUrl: 'contacts.detail.html',
        controller: function($scope, $stateParams){
          $scope.person = $scope.contacts[$stateParams.id];
        },
        onEnter: function(){
          console.log("enter contacts.detail");
        }
    })
})
```

`

and i call it as

`<a ui-sref="contacts.detail({id: 1})">My first contact<a>`

Why am I doing this way? Because, my template from the server is different for different contacts, the layout is different.

Comment: Unless you have other states under contacts, I am fairly sure you don't have to do 2 states here, rather you can populate both views from the top level state. Here is an example for inspiration using http://dotjem.github.io/angular-routing/ -- http://plnkr.co/edit/Qbf2tPalqknQQziJDWJN?p=preview

View targeting is more complex in ui-router though, which is why I choose the other router for the sample, if you need the nested state that should also work with dotJEM Angular Routing

Comment: @Jens: it works like a charm, let me wait for answers, if not i would go with DotJem lib as you suggested. Thanks much.

Comment: No problem, the two frameworks have allot of similarities, and I think you can do the same in UI-Router targeting views like: "@contacts" or something... But I honestly have no idea, I never liked their view model... In the dotJEM sample I used stupid simple names for both views, it is recommended that views are named according to their parent view, so a more correct name for the child view would be: "main.child"... but that is just good practice. Views are completely autonomous (I think the term is) in dotJEM routing.

Comment: posted as an issue https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1197

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, [posting the issue on GitHub](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1197) got me the answer from the collaborator.

So, here is the thing. The params have to be "named different" even though they are carrying the same information. Kinda weird, but works.

In the template:

`<a ui-sref="contacts.detail({id: 1, duplicate_id: 1})">My first contact<a>`

and in the javascript

`

```
$stateProvider
    .state('contacts', {
        abstract: true,

        //my whole point is to get the id=1 here :(

        url: '/contacts/:duplicate_id', //using duplicate_id here
        templateUrl: function($stateParams){} //...$stateParams will have :duplicate_id key
    }) 


    .state('contacts.detail', {
        url: '/:id', //using the real one here
        templateUrl: function($stateParams){} //....$stateParams will have :id key

    });
```

`
UPDATE: I found that the url in this case repeats the same attribute twice which is okay for me as of now. Any suggestions welcome.

Hope this helps!

Comment: did you find any other better way?

Comment: To avoid repeating the same attribute, you can pass ID only to the parent controller, assign it to a $scope variable and then access the variable in the child controller. This will work fine because you can access parent $scope from the child controller without any problem.

This is also the best practice for building RESTful applications.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
$stateProvider
.state('contacts', {
    abstract: true,

    url: '/contacts/:id/',
    templateUrl: function($stateParams){} 
}) 


.state('contacts.detail', {
    url: 'details', 
    templateUrl: function($stateParams){}

});
```

So now if you want to go to `contact.details` and pass id which will also be available in the parent abstract state:

```
<a ui-sref="contacts.detail({id: 1})">My first contact<a>
```

and the url in your browser should be like: `/contacts/1/details`